# How to destroy ckeditor in Angular application?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm using the ckeditor4 in my Angular application. When I navigate away from the page the console gives a warning like this:

> [CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-destroy-iframe.
>       ckeditor.js:21 [CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to http‌://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-editor-destroy-iframe

How should I safely unload the ckeditor component?

Comment: i found the solution. u can do like this issue, [Error code: editor-destroy-iframe](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/24)

Comment: I don't see any solution at the link you posted.   A number of vague comments and suggestions on an open bug report.   Can you be more specific on what the solution is?

Comment: please see my answer here on how to handle this without the `divarea` plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525867/angular-ng-ckeditor-and-the-editor-destroy-iframe-bug/52655850#52655850

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

1. Add the plugins 'divarea' in your html like this:

   `<ckeditor [config]={extraPlugins: 'divarea'}></ckeditor>`

At this point the console will still have have a 404 error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

2. Finally, you need to change the package address in your index.html from "full" to "full-all".

   `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>`

[reference](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/24)

Comment: please see my answer here on how to handle this without the `divarea` plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525867/angular-ng-ckeditor-and-the-editor-destroy-iframe-bug/52655850#52655850

Answer (score 1):

The details in the page referenced in the error says:

> The editor's  could not be destroyed correctly because it had
>   been unloaded before the editor was destroyed. Make sure to destroy
>   the editor before detaching it from the DOM.

You should do your cleanup in your Angular Component's onDestroy event, that way it will be destroyed before Angular removes the surrounding HTML elements.  Here are the docs on onDestroy:

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy

Comment: thank u for your help

Comment: This is the correct solution. Using the 'divarea' plugin fundamentally changes the behaviour of the CKeditor - now it will NOT load its standard contentCss file but instead all the styles from your website will spill into the div. Maybe you want that, but I find most people don't.

Comment: Actually, this is __not__ the correct answer. When ngOnDestroy is called the DOM has __already__ been unloaded, which is exactly what causes the CKEditor console error message. See this link for more details: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14252 (and so far it appears nobody has found a solution, other than wait for the Angular team to correct the documentation and implement a method which allows us to know __when__ the component is about to be destroyed).